# iOS: where should I save clientId and clientSecret in my application?

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0

My requirement is following

a.) The client registers to an `Authorization Server` and receives `clientId` and `clientSecret`

b.) The app needs to save it since this will be generated once for the app.

c.) The app requests `AccessToken` by supplying `clientId` and `clientSecret` and gets `accessToken` back

d.) The app then reuses `accessToken` to access protected resource on `Resource Server`

**Question**
a.) Where should I safely save `clientId` and `clientSecret`?
b.) Everytime when app starts, it requests for new `accessToken` from server by exchanging `clientId` and `clientSecret`. Does this flow sounds good? any issues?